# How to install pandas using pip and Python Package Index (PyPI)?

Tags: python, pandas, installation

I need to use panda in my project, therefore I tried to follow [pandas 1.5.3](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/) instructions, which lead me to [pip 23.0.1](https://pypi.org/project/pip/), and subsequently to [Installation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/), but to no avail.

I would prefer not to use anaconda.
I would like to use Python Package Index (PyPI) if it is feasible.

I tried the following:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xP869.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXRV6.png)

And this is my code and the error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJX2u.png)
This does not appear to work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `...\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\` is not in your `PATH` variable. you can add this folder to your `PATH`.

You can find out how to add to `PATH` [here](https://www.wikihow.com/Change-the-PATH-Environment-Variable-on-Windows)

Comment: I would like to use C:\ as the directory to put the pip, sorry I should've mention that. I got to this window I got to the Edit environment variable window, how will I edit the path?